# How to count exactly the same number of values for different groups over different years, starting from the earliest common month-day in r?

Tags: r, date, grouping, counter

I have values of 2 biomarkers ('analyte'), measured with 2 different 'methods' over 2 different periods ('old' methods over 4 days from 2022-06-03 to 2022-06-06, and 'new' methods over 7 days from 2023-06-01 to 2023-06-07).

**Question:**  How to count exactly the same (maximal) number of values for 'old' and 'new' methods in a new column, by analyte, starting from the earliest common period, considering month-day regardless of the year?
For example, in the desired output data below, the new 'count' column shows:
n=16 values for old and new methods of the first analyte 'chol', and
n=18 values for old and new methods of the second analyte 'ldh'.

**Input data:**

```
dat0 <-
structure(list(analyte = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("amy", "auu", "chol", "ggt", 
"iron", "ldh", "pal", "prot", "trig", "uree", "ureeu", "uric"
), class = "factor"), method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("new", "old"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 
    1654214400, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 
    1654387200, 1654387200, 1654387200, 1654473600, 1654473600, 
    1654473600, 1654473600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 
    1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
    1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685750400, 
    1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685836800, 
    1685836800, 1685836800, 1685836800, 1685923200, 1685923200, 
    1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1686009600, 
    1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 
    1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000, 
    1686096000, 1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 
    1654214400, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 
    1654300800, 1654300800, 1654387200, 1654387200, 1654387200, 
    1654387200, 1654387200, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 
    1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 
    1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 
    1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
    1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685836800, 1685836800, 
    1685836800, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 
    1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686096000, 
    1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), value = c(2.84, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 2.84, 2.81, 
    2.8, 2.83, 2.82, 2.82, 2.8, 2.82, 2.81, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 
    2.74, 2.76, 2.77, 2.79, 2.76, 2.81, 2.73, 2.75, 2.77, 2.78, 
    2.76, 2.86, 2.73, 2.78, 2.84, 2.82, 2.8, 2.74, 2.76, 2.79, 
    2.82, 2.8, 2.76, 2.77, 2.83, 2.85, 2.83, 2.78, 2.74, 2.8, 
    2.8, 2.79, 2.85, 2.75, 2.76, 2.78, 2.82, 2.76, 2.86, 121, 
    119, 113, 117, 119, 123, 120, 117, 118, 125, 121, 121, 124, 
    123, 117, 115, 113, 120, 113, 113, 115, 117, 119, 115, 111, 
    111, 113, 116, 115, 111, 115, 112, 118, 115, 113, 106, 118, 
    113, 113, 113, 110, 114, 113, 117, 111, 111, 115, 120, 112, 
    113, 114, 108)), row.names = c(NA, -107L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Desired output data:**

```
dat1 <-
structure(list(analyte = c("chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", "chol", 
"chol", "chol", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", 
"ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", 
"ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", 
"ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", 
"ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", 
"ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh", "ldh"
), method = c("old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new"), date = structure(c(1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 
1654214400, 1654214400, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 
1654387200, 1654387200, 1654387200, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 
1654473600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 
1685577600, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 
1685836800, 1685836800, 1685836800, 1685836800, 1685923200, 1685923200, 
1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1686009600, 1686009600, 
1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686096000, 1686096000, 
1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000, 1686096000, 1654214400, 1654214400, 
1654214400, 1654214400, 1654214400, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 
1654300800, 1654300800, 1654300800, 1654387200, 1654387200, 1654387200, 
1654387200, 1654387200, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 
1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1654473600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 
1685577600, 1685577600, 1685577600, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685664000, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685836800, 
1685836800, 1685836800, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 1685923200, 
1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686009600, 1686096000, 1686096000, 
1686096000, 1686096000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    value = c(2.84, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 2.84, 2.81, 2.8, 2.83, 
    2.82, 2.82, 2.8, 2.82, 2.81, 2.79, 2.82, 2.84, 2.74, 2.76, 
    2.77, 2.79, 2.76, 2.81, 2.73, 2.75, 2.77, 2.78, 2.76, 2.86, 
    2.73, 2.78, 2.84, 2.82, 2.8, 2.74, 2.76, 2.79, 2.82, 2.8, 
    2.76, 2.77, 2.83, 2.85, 2.83, 2.78, 2.74, 2.8, 2.8, 2.79, 
    2.85, 2.75, 2.76, 2.78, 2.82, 2.76, 2.86, 121, 119, 113, 
    117, 119, 123, 120, 117, 118, 125, 121, 121, 124, 123, 117, 
    115, 113, 120, 113, 113, 115, 117, 119, 115, 111, 111, 113, 
    116, 115, 111, 115, 112, 118, 115, 113, 106, 118, 113, 113, 
    113, 110, 114, 113, 117, 111, 111, 115, 120, 112, 113, 114, 
    108), count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
    14, 15, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -107L))
```

Thanks for help

Comment: In `dplyr` : `dat0 %>% mutate(count = row_number(), .by = c(analyte, method))`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but starting dates in 2022 (old method) and in 2023 (new method) are not similar, i.e., if the old method of chol starts from 2022-06-03, I woul dexpect that the new one starts from 2023-06-03, both having the same n=16 number of values.

Comment: FYI, your `dat0` has 107 rows and your `dat1` expected output has only 68 rows. Are you intended a filtering action as well, or is your `dat1` inconsistent? I ran RonakShah's code on `dat1` and it produced the same `count` you have. If there's a problem, then please explain the difference and correct the assumedly-incorrect  `dat1$count`.

Comment: Thanks r2evans for this clarification. Yes, in the initial version, `dat1` was filtered to only keep values with an identical count. But for greater clarity, I've now edited `dat1` so that to have the same rows number as `dat0` (unwanted values are flagged as NAs).

Comment: @denis To clarify, when you mention starting from the earliest common date, did you mean based on common month and date but not year? For example, June 3 2022 and June 3 2023 both starting on June 3?

Comment: @Ben, yes exactly, the same month-day period from one year to the next. Sorry for not clarifying this and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @Ben, I've corrected the title and the question, accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this might help in moving forward. I get a bit of a difference in output, but it may be justifiable. This assumes that sequences will not wrap around years or have more complex occurrences.

First, you will need to separate your date to consider `month` and `day` without `year`. You can sort or `arrange` the data for each `analyte` using `month` and `day`. The first day of the year where there is overlap (both "new" and "old" available for a given day and `analyte`) will be indicated with `TRUE` in a new column called `overlap`.

A `count` will be computed for each `method` and `analyte` where there is `overlap`.

Next part, you can `arrange` by `analyte` and `count`, and `filter` or keep rows where there are both methods available for a given `count` and `analyte`.

I believe the difference in output is that the following only includes exactly 14 tests for "ldh" for both methods, even though one ends on June 5 and the other June 6. If you wanted them to continue with the same end date, this could be modified.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat0 |>
  separate(date, c('year', 'month', 'day'), sep = "-", remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) |>
  arrange(analyte, month, day) |>
  mutate(overlap = all(c("old", "new") %in% method), .by = c(analyte, month, day)) |>
  mutate(count = cumsum(overlap), .by = c(analyte, method)) |>
  filter(overlap & all(c("old", "new") %in% method), .by = c(analyte, count)) |>
  arrange(analyte, method, date)
```

**Output**

```
   analyte method date                 year month   day  value overlap count
   <fct>   <fct>  <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <lgl>   <int>
 1 chol    new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3   2.73 TRUE        1
 2 chol    new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3   2.78 TRUE        2
 3 chol    new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3   2.84 TRUE        3
 4 chol    new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3   2.82 TRUE        4
 5 chol    new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3   2.8  TRUE        5
 6 chol    new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4   2.74 TRUE        6
 7 chol    new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4   2.76 TRUE        7
 8 chol    new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4   2.79 TRUE        8
 9 chol    new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4   2.82 TRUE        9
10 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.8  TRUE       10
11 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.76 TRUE       11
12 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.77 TRUE       12
13 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.83 TRUE       13
14 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.85 TRUE       14
15 chol    new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5   2.83 TRUE       15
16 chol    new    2023-06-06 00:00:00  2023     6     6   2.78 TRUE       16
17 chol    old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3   2.84 TRUE        1
18 chol    old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3   2.79 TRUE        2
19 chol    old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3   2.82 TRUE        3
20 chol    old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3   2.84 TRUE        4
21 chol    old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3   2.84 TRUE        5
22 chol    old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4   2.81 TRUE        6
23 chol    old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4   2.8  TRUE        7
24 chol    old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4   2.83 TRUE        8
25 chol    old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4   2.82 TRUE        9
26 chol    old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5   2.82 TRUE       10
27 chol    old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5   2.8  TRUE       11
28 chol    old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5   2.82 TRUE       12
29 chol    old    2022-06-06 00:00:00  2022     6     6   2.81 TRUE       13
30 chol    old    2022-06-06 00:00:00  2022     6     6   2.79 TRUE       14
31 chol    old    2022-06-06 00:00:00  2022     6     6   2.82 TRUE       15
32 chol    old    2022-06-06 00:00:00  2022     6     6   2.84 TRUE       16
33 ldh     new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3 113    TRUE        1
34 ldh     new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3 106    TRUE        2
35 ldh     new    2023-06-03 00:00:00  2023     6     3 118    TRUE        3
36 ldh     new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4 113    TRUE        4
37 ldh     new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4 113    TRUE        5
38 ldh     new    2023-06-04 00:00:00  2023     6     4 113    TRUE        6
39 ldh     new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5 110    TRUE        7
40 ldh     new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5 114    TRUE        8
41 ldh     new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5 113    TRUE        9
42 ldh     new    2023-06-05 00:00:00  2023     6     5 117    TRUE       10
43 ldh     new    2023-06-06 00:00:00  2023     6     6 111    TRUE       11
44 ldh     new    2023-06-06 00:00:00  2023     6     6 111    TRUE       12
45 ldh     new    2023-06-06 00:00:00  2023     6     6 115    TRUE       13
46 ldh     new    2023-06-06 00:00:00  2023     6     6 120    TRUE       14
47 ldh     old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3 121    TRUE        1
48 ldh     old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3 119    TRUE        2
49 ldh     old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3 113    TRUE        3
50 ldh     old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3 117    TRUE        4
51 ldh     old    2022-06-03 00:00:00  2022     6     3 119    TRUE        5
52 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 123    TRUE        6
53 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 120    TRUE        7
54 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 117    TRUE        8
55 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 118    TRUE        9
56 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 125    TRUE       10
57 ldh     old    2022-06-04 00:00:00  2022     6     4 121    TRUE       11
58 ldh     old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5 121    TRUE       12
59 ldh     old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5 124    TRUE       13
60 ldh     old    2022-06-05 00:00:00  2022     6     5 123    TRUE       14
```

Comment: Ben, it works perfectly, even on my own database which contains 12 analytes, and even adding 2 levels of subgroups (analyzers (n=5) and quality control levels (n=3)). You understood things perfectly, and it is not surprising that 'date_ends' do not necessarily correspond between 'old' and 'new' methods since the number of values can vary from one day to the next (over the same period, totals may therefore vary substantially); the objective was to start 'old' and 'new' counts from the same 'date_start' and these counts to be strictly identical between both methods. Thank you so much!